# Answering Android phone on a Mac Mini

Tags: mac

I'm looking to be able to answer my Android cell phone when I am working on my Mac Mini. I see ways to do it if one has an iPhone, but can't find anything if one has an Android. I appreciate any input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done in the Apple infrastructure. You might want to see if you can replicate some of the functionality with Google Phone.